# How to remove elements from list but keep the value `False`

Tags: python

I have the following list: `[0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0]` and I just want to remove the value `0` from it. But everything so I tried also removes `False` from the list.

Note that the value `0` could be anywhere in the list.

For example:

```py
while 0 in array:
        array.remove(0)
```

OR

```py
a = [x for x in array if int(x) != 0]
```

Results in `[1, None, 2, 1]`

And I am looking for `[1, None, 2, False, 1]` as a result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `if not x is 0`

Comment: @RafaelC that relies on an *implementation detail* of CPython that should not be relied on. Rather, rely on the guarantee that `bool` objects are singletons, and can be compared by identity

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why it shouldn't be relied on? Is there any possibility that, at some point in the future, `False is 0` returns `True`?

Comment: @Austin it is, thanks. I didn't see it.

Comment: @RafaelC because it is possible that `0 is not 0` will be `True`, int objects are not guaranteed to be singletons, and indeed, are not outside small integers (-2 to 255 I believe).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga wow, I see now. I had it for me that it was *absolutely true* that ints were singletons, not sure why. SO lesson of the day for me ;} Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`False` is always equal to `0`, so you cannot just check for equality here. Instead you can do it like this:

```
a = [x for x in array if x is False or x != 0]
```

Comment: This is wrong. It is an *implementation detail* that small ints are cached in CPython and it should not be relied on. In this case, you should rely on the *language guarantee* that booleans are singletons, and can be reliably compared using identity

Comment: You should *remove the incorrect answer entirely*.

Answer (score 3):

```
[ x for x in array if x is False or x != 0]
```

Your initial attempt was failing because `int(False)` was evaluated to 0.

Comment: It won't remove the `False` item because `x is False` will return True, before the `x != 0` check is evaluated.